# Removing element IDs whose element has gone missing in Revit API using C#

Tags: revit-api, revit

We have a model. The central model has become corrupt due to too many missing elements. After following the procedure outlined [in this documentation](http://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2017/ENU/?guid=GUID-9AFAAE6B-4107-4478-8B80-53467FE118DB), we are unable to find an instance of the model where these elements exist.  There are thousands of sequentially numbered ids - cause is unknown. Perhaps someone copied into the model and immediately removed elements leaving the ids behind? We don't know.

Is there a way to remove element ids of elements that no longer exist in the file programmatically? I don't know what that would be a collection of.

Potentially a very costly (perceived to be Revit induced) problem for us.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot have an element id without an element associated with it.

Regardless, you normally delete elements by specifying just the element id, or a collection of ids, passed in to the `Document.Delete` method:

http://www.revitapidocs.com/2017/dd023de2-cf2b-03ca-6f45-89b5e867fe92.htm

So if you know which element ids you want to remove, all should be fine.

No idea how the method will behave if the elements are not there after all, as you say...